# Assert that a method from System.IO.Fakes was called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, microsoft-fakes

I have a legacy class that we can't refactor now and inside it's using classes from `System.IO` (checks if a file exists, check if a directory exists, creates a directory, etc) and we need to create unit tests for this class. I've added `System.Fakes` and I was wondering if there is a method to assert that inside the class the method `Directory.Exists` was called, for example or `Directory.CreateDirectory` was called with a certain parameter. These calls are internals.

Comment: When setting up the fake, use a flag in the delegate to indicate that it was invoked and assert the flag

Comment: I was thinking at this, but I was looking for something build in... Like NSubstitute has, for example...